# Xcode swift - AVAudio Player not working after Copy Bundle

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am working on using AVAudio player and I am currently getting the following error - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

I looked and on various solutions the problem was that the desired file was not in the copy bundle resources area. But the file has been added there to the desired target, so not sure of the solution.

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(Buckfast)
public class Buckfast: CAPPlugin {

@objc func echo(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    let value = call.getString("value") ?? ""
    call.success([
        "value": value
    ])

    var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "wav") {
   let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

   do {
       bombSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
       bombSoundEffect?.play()
   } catch {
       // couldn't load file :(
   }
}

}
```

}

[Copy Bundle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PS04.png)
[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJOKk.png)

Comment: try to unwrap using if let like `if let path =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "wav")  { }` and Please add your code instead of screenshot

Comment: I added the line of code and everything inside the the if doesn't run as it does not find the file in the bundle

Comment: Where is the file itself located in the project? If you have it in the folder you should add the path as well e.g `folder1/folder2/1.wav`

Comment: You can see the path in the bundle image. The file is inside the same folder as the swift file inside the target.

Comment: Yeah both AVKit and AVFoundation are being imported in a header file Plugin.h

#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import<AVKit/AVKit.h>

Comment: But the issue is the file not being found, the If let will stop the code running inside it when the file is not found, so the print message will not run.

Comment: Kishan Bhatiya  - Please stop deleting comments when your solution doesn't work, makes it harder for other users to help find solutions

Comment: As from bundle image, you have to add sound file to your project's folder not under pod's folder.

Comment: That has allowed the code to pass by the If let, so the file is being found. But the app is still not playing any sound

Comment: Hi, after cleaning and rebuilding it completely it now works. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to unwrap using `if let` like

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "wav") { 
}
```

The file was not found when residing in the pods folder. The file needs to be placed in the Apps Copy Bundle Resources instead.